# How do I make a loop check

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to test if a `local_key` already exists, if it exists generate another `local_key` and check again

```
// Here I go throught an object and try to return a index
const local_key = messagesRow.map((message, key) => {
    return message.local_key;
}).indexOf(message.local_key);

// If it returns 0 or bigger, it means that the local_key already exists
if(local_key >= 0){
    message.local_key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999);
}
```

**EDIT**
I want to recheck every time, cause if the `local_key` exists and I generate another one, this new `local_key` maybe exists too

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Isnt this working?

Comment: Yes, but I want to recheck, cause it may generate a local_key that already exists again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to generate a key is using `uniqid`

```
$id = md5(uniqid(date('d/m/Y H:i'), true));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but you are iterating over the whole array, where you only need one match.  I would recommend to use some javascript library like underscore (http://underscorejs.org/) which provides nice find function.

Using random number from 0 to 99999 is not a good solution -  there is probability that you will generate duplicate number.  Better choice would be some UUID / GUID
(see duscussion here: [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript) ) -  and there will be no need at all to search for it in array as this is unique